# Preserving the size of an object

Tags: mesh, export

If I import a Stanford ply mesh, scale it using <kbd>S</kbd>, export it, and import it again, the mesh data hasn't actually changed.

How can I use blender to scale the vertices contained in mesh data, and export them correctly *or* preserve the scale of the model?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this, you can try applying the scale with `Ctrl` + `A`..

Comment: Ahhh I didn't know about the apply! Is this a stupid question, or is it worth leaving it up for other fools like me?

Comment: heh, It might be helpful as we've had a mix of these types of questions including some about armatures etc, I will post a short answer.

Comment: What version of blender are you using? 2.67 applies the scale on export so you dont need to apply scale.

Comment: I'm still on 2.62 - I need to get off the Ubuntu 12.04 repository and upgrade on my own.

Comment: @ajwood You could also use the irie PPA for blender, http://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa (if you want the SVN versions that is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the case you mentioned above as ***all exporters bundled with Blender will always apply the scale on export*** and in some cases, you can choose to apply the modifiers and other things as well.

You more than likely missed or changed something or it is a bug, try updating the version of Blender you are using.

Comment: This is incorrect. the exporter applies scale on export so there is no need to apply scale manually.

Comment: @ideasman42 ..In forgetting that I was unable to reproduce his 'error', I forgot to mention that..

Comment: It must have been fixed between my version 2.62 and the current version. I've come across another importing 'error' but I'll hold my tongue until I'm running the most recent version :P